# Free IP scanner for OS X?

Tags: network

I am looking for a, preferably free tool that would scan current network (using the mark) for alive hosts.

It needs to be able to resolve hostnames and preferably to support bonjour too.

Comment: Please have a look at our guide to [ask] a shopping question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget about [Nmap](http://nmap.org/) which is a must-have tool for any network admin or IT type - use the `-sn` flag for ping Scan, among many other options.

Answer (score 0):

**Angry IP Scanner** is a free IP scanning tool [[download]](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipscan/files/ipscan3-binary/3.0-beta6/ipscan-mac-3.0-beta6.zip).